# Finding Coefficients of a Double Fourier Series Related to Bessel Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, bessel-functions

This is from the lecture notes of MIT.

[image]

I am confused about the sentence "where the $a_{nm}$ and $b_{nm}$ are found from the ICs". It is from problem 3 [in this pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/assignments/probpde3dsolns.pdf).

I tried to use orthogonality, but I don't know how to deal with the $J$ and the double summation.

Could anyone kindly help how to do that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the following orthogonality

$$\eqalign{
  & {\varphi _{mn}}(r,\theta ) = {J_{3n}}\left( {\sqrt {{\lambda _{nm}}} r} \right)\cos \left( {3n\theta } \right)  \cr 
  & \int_{r = 0}^R {\int_{\theta  = 0}^{2\pi } {{\varphi _{mn}}{\varphi _{pq}}rdrd\theta } }  = {\delta _{mp}}{\delta _{nq}}\int_{r = 0}^R {\int_{\theta  = 0}^{2\pi } {\varphi _{mn}^2rdrd\theta } }  \cr} $$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker's delta.